# Is there any open source system for keyword search on XML documents?

Tags: xml, open-source, xpath, xquery, keyword-search

I found lot of open source XML databases (TPOX, Timber , DBXML), but they are working on XPath and XQuery, I need  a system which is developed for the purpose of "Keyword search on XML documents".

Comment: you don't need xml database to do keyword search.. you just need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the XML databases provide keyword indexing on the XML documents in them.  You are not just limited to XPath expressions.  You can do a keyword search across all the documents in the database.

Often times, you can express your keyword queries (and process the results of the query) in XQuery.  See exist-db for an example: http://exist.sourceforge.net/kwic.html

There is support for keyword limited to particular elements or you could just do keyword across the document as a whole.  See the XQuery Full-text spec for all the options: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/

BaseX is another open source XML database that supports the full-text (ie keyword searching) spec: http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/dbis/basex/

If you want open source fulltext search without the database though you might want to look at the older XQengine - http://xqengine.sourceforge.net/ - or, like someone else said, just use Lucene and index all the text in a document that way.

Comment: thanks, my question is answered.for more information, I want you to take a look on the following systems(XRANK is a Ranked keyword search over XML documents on  http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cbotev/XRank.pdf) and (XSeek is  A Semantic XML Search Engine Using Keywords on http://xseek.asu.edu/xseekdemo.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a "Keyword search" is, but you can set up a search engine, such as lucene/solr to index your data and then search through that.